# Timer on trivia game keeps speeding up on restart

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, prototype

So I made a trivia game for class and every time I hit Restart the seconds get faster, or if I click too many answers at once? Is there a way to prevent multiple clicks from happening?
https://alil0rphan.github.io/TriviaGame/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 // Variables that I need
    var correct = 0;
  wrong = 0;
  noanswer = 0;
  question = 0;
  timer = 10;
  $('.restart').hide();
 //Function to start game
 function setupGame() {
  $('.timeLeft').hide();
  $('.question').hide();
  $('.options').hide();
  $('.result').hide();
  $('.restart').hide();
  $('.directions').show();
 };
 //Establish start button behavior
 $('.start').on('click', function(startGame) {
  $('.timeLeft').show();
  $('.question').show();
  $('.options').show();
  $('.result').show();
  $('.restart').show();
  $('.start').hide();
  $('.directions').hide();
  showQuestion();
 });
 //Showing the question
 function showQuestion(){
  $(this).off('click');
  $('.result').html('');
  startTimer();
  var obj = questions[question];
  
  var qText = obj.q_text;
  $('.question').html(qText);
  
  var qAnswers = [obj.q_options_1, obj.q_options_2, obj.q_options_3, obj.q_options_4]
  $('.options').html('');
  for (var i = 0; i < qAnswers.length; i++) {
   var ans = qAnswers[i];
   var id = i + 1;
   var first = '<li id="'+id+'">'
   var last = '</li>'
   $('.options').append(first+ans+last);
  }

  for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
   $('#'+j).click(function(){
    showAnswer($(this).attr('id'));
   });
  }
  $(this).off('click');
 }
 //Shows the answer
 function showAnswer(num) {
  stopTimer();
  timer = 10;
  var count = question;
  var obj = questions[count];
  var objCorrect = obj.q_correct_option
  if (num == 0){
   noanswer++
   $('.result').html('Please Answer the Questions');
  } else if (num == objCorrect) {
   correct++
   $('.result').html('Correct!');
  } else {
   wrong++
   $('.result').html('Incorrect!');
   $('#'+num).addClass('wrong');
  }
  $('#'+objCorrect).addClass('correct');
  $('.result').append('<br> Correct: ' + correct + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('Wrong: ' + wrong + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('Missed: ' + noanswer);
  question++
  if (question < 15) {
   setTimeout(showQuestion, 2000); 
  } else {
   setTimeout(gameOver);
  }
  $(this).off('click');
 }
    //Establish timer for each question
    function startTimer(){
  timer = 10;
  $('.timeLeft').html('Time Remaining: ' + timer + ' seconds');
  counter = setInterval(runTimer, 1000);
  $(this).off('click');
    }
    // run the timer
    function runTimer(){
     
     // remove a second
  timer--

  // display timer
  $('.timeLeft').html('Time Remaining: ' + timer + ' seconds');
  
  // you ran out of time
  if (timer === 0){

   // stop the counter from going negative
   stopTimer();

   // show answer and mark no answer
   showAnswer(0);
  }
    }
    // stop counting down
    function stopTimer(){
  clearInterval(counter);
    }

    //Establishes a restart buttom
    $('.restart').on('click', restart);
 // Restart
 function restart() {
  stopTimer();
  $('.start').show();
  correct = 0;
  wrong = 0;
  noanswer = 0;
  question = 0;
  timer = 10;
  setupGame();
 }
 
 function gameOver() {
  
  $('.options').html('Hit Restart if you want to try again!');
  $('.question').html('');
  $('.result').html('<br> Correct: ' + correct + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('Wrong: ' + wrong + '<br>');
  $('.result').append('Missed: ' + noanswer);

  if (correct == 15) {
   $('.timeLeft').html('You are a Menu Master!');
  } else if (correct > wrong) {
   $('.timeLeft').html('Almost! See if you can get the all correct.');
  } else if (noanswer == 15) {
   $('.timeLeft').html('Do you even care?');
  } else if (wrong > correct) {
   $('.timeLeft').html('Sad! Try again.');
  } else if (wrong == correct) {
   $('.timeLeft').html('You should keep studying the menu.');
  } else {
   $('.timeLeft').html('Thanks for trying!');
  }
  $('.restart').on('click', restart);
 }

});
 //Establish questions
 function question(number, text, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, ans) {
  this.id = number;
  this.q_text = text;
  this.q_options_1 = opt1;
  this.q_options_2 = opt2;
  this.q_options_3 = opt3;
  this.q_options_4 = opt4;
  this.q_correct_option = ans;
 };

 var question1 = new question (
  1,
  'What makes Slims unique?',
  'They are smaller.',
  'They have only meats or cheese, we can\'t add veggies or sauce.',
  'They get less mayo.',
  'They get extra veggies.',
  2
 )

 var question2 = new question (
  2,
  'Which subs and clubs have lettuce and tomato?',
  'All of them.',
  'All but the ones with tuna.',
  'The clubs only.',
  'The subs only.',
  1
 )

 var question3 = new question (
  3,
  'Which sandwiches have no mayo?',
  'The 3, 5 and 15.',
  'The 2, 3, 4, 14, 16 and 17.',
  'The 6 and 13.',
  'The Gargantuan.',
  1
 )

 var question4 = new question (
  4,
  'Which sandwiches get Onions, Herbs and Sauce?',
  'The ones with Cheese.',
  'The ones with Tuna.',
  'The Billy Club and the Ultimate Porker.',
  'The ones with Vito.',
  4
 )

 var question5 = new question (
  5,
  'What comes on the #8?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Ham.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, Dijon, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, more Beef and Cheese.',
  3
 )

 var question6 = new question (
  6,
  'How many pieces of bacon do we put as a portion?',
  '4.',
  'Enough to cover the sandwich.',
  '6.',
  '5.',
  4
 )

 var question7 = new question (
  7,
  'What comes on a #14?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Turkey and Bacon.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, Dijon, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Ham and Bacon.',
  2
 )

 var question8 = new question (
  8,
  'What comes on the #10?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Ham.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, Dijon, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, more Beef and Cheese.',
  4
 )

 var question9 = new question (
  9,
  'What comes on the #17?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Ham.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, Dijon, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, more Beef and Cheese.',
  1
 )

 var question10 = new question (
  10,
  'Which sandwiches have Avo spread on them?',
  'The 5 and 9.',
  'The 6, 12 and 13.',
  'The 3 and 15.',
  'The 16 and 17.',
  2
 )

 var question11 = new question (
  11,
  'What comes on the #12?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Ham.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Turkey, Cheese, Avo and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, more Beef and Cheese.',
  3
 )

 var question12 = new question (
  12,
  'What comes on the #9?',
  'Mayo, tomato, onions, lettuce, sauce, herbs, Vito, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, Dijon, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, more Beef and Cheese.',
  1
 )

 var question13 = new question (
  13,
  'What comes on the #11?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Ham.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, Dijon, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Turkey, Ham and Cheese.',
  4
 )

 var question14 = new question (
  14,
  'What comes on the #16?',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Ham.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Bacon and Turkey.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Turkey, Ham and Cheese.',
  'Mayo, tomato, lettuce, Beef, more Beef and Cheese.',
  2
 )

 var question15 = new question (
  15,
  'Which sandwiches have cucumbers?',
  'Sandwiches with Tuna.',
  'Sandwiches with Avo.',
  'The 3, 6, 12, 13 and 15.',
  'All of the above.',
  4
 )
 var questions = [question1, question2, question3, question4, question5, question6, question7, question8, question9, question10, question11, question12, question13, question14, question15]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
 <title>Jimmy Trivia</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='assets/css/style.css'>
 <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='assets/javascript/app.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
 <section id='container'>
  <img src='assets/images/jimmy.png' title="Jimmy John's" alt="Jimmy John's Logo" id='jjlogo'>
  <h1>Menu Madness</h1>
  <button class='start'>Start</button>
  <p class='directions'>Press Start to continue the quiz. <br>Only select one answer at a time. <br>Press Restart if you are having any problems.</p>
  <h2 class='timeLeft'></h2>
  <h3 class='question'></h3>
  <p class='options'></p>
  <p class='result'></p>
  <button class='restart'>Restart</button>
  <br>
  <br>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope that makes sense. It's been driving me crazy.

Comment: Essentially if you click too many answers the timer keeps getting faster. I don't know if it's because the run timer feature piles on making the seconds decrement faster?

Comment: If you have trouble with clicks happening too fast, you can shut them off.

document.addEventListener("click",handler,true);

function handler(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

This will stop clicks.

You may want to consider popping up a clear overlay over everything for a set amount of time after a click event too.

Comment: That works, but How to I re-enable clicks after the next question pops up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to ignore clicks on buttons, then reenable them after an amount of time.

```
$('#id').on('click', function(){
    // use a class on the buttons like pause_btn for the buttons that need to timeout.
    $('.pause_btn').prop('disabled',true);
    setTimeout(function(){
       // enable click after 1 second
       $('.pause-btn').prop('disabled',false);
    },1000); // change this to set delay in thousandths of a second.
});
```